# Multiplication by recursion - how are values added?

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to understand what is happening in my recursion step `return x + times(x, y-1)`.

Specifically `times(x, y-1)` Since there is no equation in the function what is happening in the recursion? I don't see how the values are added.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int times(int x, int y)
{
    if (x == 0 || y == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (y == 1)
        return x;
    else
        return x + times(x, y - 1);
}

int main()
{
    int x, y;

    cout << "Enter two numbers to be multiplied seperated by a space: ";
    cin >> x >> y;
    cout << "The product is " << times(x, y) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you see the `+` sign before the recursive call? That's the addition.

Comment: Try to understand something simple. `times(2,2)`, for instance.

Comment: expand: `times(2,3) = 2 + times(2,2) = 2 + 2 + times(2,1) = 2 + 2 + 2 = 6`

Comment: What the recursion step does is `a * n = a + a * (n - 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand recursion is to write all the stack trace on paper.

Let's take an example of times(3, 2):

```
Call 1: times(3, 2) -> returns 6

Call 2: 3 + times(3, 1) -> returns (3 + 3), that is 6

Call 3: times(3, 1) -> returns 3
```

So, the final answer is 6.

`x + times(x, y-1)`: It's a way of representing multiplication using addition. For example:

1) 3 * 2 = (3 + 3)

2) 4 * 3 = (4 + 4 + 4 + 4)

**@dxiv** mentioned it perfectly, `a * n = a + a * (n - 1)`.

Comment: I thought times() was a user defined function. I didn't see an equation in the function to do math.